# Mounting as USB drive before syncing?

Tags: sync, outlook

I'm going through the different alternatives to synchronize my ICS-based Samsung Nexus with Outlook.

While sync works fine over wifi, I'd rather use USB which The Missing Sync is supposed to be able to sync over USB, but [the documentation](http://www.markspace.com/products/android/windows/android-guide.html#mount-usb-drive) seems meant for older releases of Android, and I don't know how to get the Samsung to work.

It says: "Before synchronizing with a USB cable, confirm that the Android device is mounted as a USB Drive on the computer", but doesn't explain what to do on ICS.

I tried either MTP or PTP, but still get the error "Unable to sync: no bluetooth, wifi, or USB connection is available".

Thank you.

---

Edit: I followed "[Missing Sync for Android: Syncing via USB](https://support.markspace.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=520)", but it fails syncing with USB:

1. The Androphone supports "USB Tethering", as seen in Settings > Wireless & 
   Networks > More... > Tethering & portable hotspot > USB Tethering. Do NOT 
   check the option!
2. Turn off the Nexus, remove the battery for 1 minute, put it back and turn the 
   Nexus back on. Wait until it fully boots.
3. Connect the Nexus to the PC with the USB cable
4. If prompted to mount the SD card, choose "Charge only"; If it is mounted 
   with no prompt, slide the Notifications section down and select "Charge only"
5. Open the Missing Sync application on the Nexus, click on the menu button 
   (three, vertical points) > Settings > Unselect "Secure Sync". Close.

   No "Secure Sync", only "Secure WiFi sync" which is checked by default
6. Click on Sync, and choose to sync via USB, and wait a few seconds for 
   syncing via USB starts.

   "Unable to sync, no bluetooth, wifi or USB connection is available".

   Unpaired wifi, tried again: "Unable to sync, no bluetooth, wifi or USB 
   connection is available"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 4.0.3 on a Samsung Galaxy S2.
To mount the internal storage and any installed SD card via the USB do the following:

1. Unplug USB cable.
2. Goto Settings -> More... -> USB utilities -> Connect storage to PC
   and follow the instructions.